# Julia's PlotlyJS not working in VS Code anymore

Tags: plotly, julia

I encountered an odd issue in VS CODE. Running the below will NOT display a chart at all:

```
using Plots
using PlotlyJS
plotlyjs()
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); 
p = Plots.plot(x, y)
display(p)
```

However, running this first (displaying the basic chart once):

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); 
p = Plots.plot(x, y)
display(p)
```

and then rerunning the first code (with PlotlyJS), it works and the PlotlyJS chart is being displayed properly. What could be causing this? I already downgraded PlotlyJS from 0.15.0 to 0.14.1 and that doesn't fix it. I also used an older vs code julia language plugin to no avail. Julia version is 1.7.0, Plots is v1.25.2. This used to work in the past, so not sure what changed.

Comment: I have Julia v1.7.0, Plots v1.23.6, PlotlyJS v0.18.8 and it all works. I also updated Plots to v1.25.2 and still works. VSCode is 1.63.2.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful - turns out the culprit was the Julia VS Code plugin after all. The insider version doesn't seem to work for me. I uninstalled that and replaced with the stable version, and now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Just so this question has a marked answer: The issue was something to do with the VS Code Insider version (see comment on question).

Comment: They finally acknowledged this as a bug here: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2651

Even worse: this made it into the real release now. At this point in time the only way to fix this is to revert to 1.5.6 and avoid 1.5.8